# Collect Network Card related information

Tags: powershell

I need a script which extracts me at least Computername, IP Address(es), Description (Alias) and MAC Address for each NIC and export it to csv

I found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/cbe013ed-7879-46e4-a0c5-44f628edcfb5/how-to-list-ip-addresses-subnets-mac-addresses-etc-in-powershell) this piece of script which covers my needs and some surplus information:

```
$Data = @()
$NetInfo = Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed 
foreach ( $nic in $Netinfo) { 
    foreach ($ip in $nic.IPv4Address) { 
        $Data += [pscustomobject] @{ Ordinateur=$nic.ComputerName; AliasNIC=$nic.InterfaceAlias; 
                                    NetworkcardName=$nic.InterfaceDescription; IP=$ip; MAC=$nic.NetAdapter.MACAddress;
                                    Status=$nic.NetAdapter.Status
                                    }
    }
 } 
 $Data | Format-Table #-HideTableHeader
```

I would like to use **export-csv**

instead of format-table but for IP address but I get strange outputs below an example for one line of output:

```
"Client01","Ethernet","Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V","MSFT_NetIPAddress (Name = "";C?8;@B8;AB8?:?55?55;55;"", CreationClassName = """", SystemCreationClassName = """", SystemName = """")","MSFT_NetIPAddress (Name = "";C?8;@B8;AB8?:?55?55;55;"", CreationClassName = """", SystemCreationClassName = """", SystemName = """")","38-F3-AB-85-EC-CF","Up"
```

Comment: Your variable $ip is an object. Use $ip.IPAdress. Or remove the second loop complete  and add an array of ip adresses instead to your ps custom object `@($nic.IPv4Address | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddress)`

Comment: That did the trick. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution from **guiwhatsthat** (see comments)

```
$Data = @()
$NetInfo = Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed 
foreach ( $nic in $Netinfo) { 
    foreach ($ip in $nic.IPv4Address) { 
        $Data += [pscustomobject] @{ Ordinateur=$nic.ComputerName; AliasNIC=$nic.InterfaceAlias; 
                                    NetworkcardName=$nic.InterfaceDescription; IP=$ip.IPAddress; MAC=$nic.NetAdapter.MACAddress;
                                    Status=$nic.NetAdapter.Status
                                    }
    }
 } 
 $Data | Format-Table #-HideTableHeader
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).